# variables used in functions

Tags: actionscript-3, function, variables, parameters

I have a stupid question. I got this variable:

```
var type:int;
```

and this function:

```
private function test(type:int):void {
}
```

when i call the function and throw in my variable type

```
test(type);
```

is there a possibility that the compiler gets confused because my variable has the same name like the functions's parameter (type = type)? i'm not certain about this topic. Normally I'd write my function's parameter like this (if such a case occurs):
    private function test(_type:int):void

just to make sure the names do not exactly match (well I hope you know what I mean).

Comment: you could test your theory by simply naming the variable something else that is not a reserved keyword, i think you may be right about that though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.

test(type) will always refer to your variable named type and not to the parameter named type, because there is no access to the parameter variable outside of the function.

However, if within the test function you called test(type) at that point it would refer to the parameter variable type because local scope takes precedence (for the sake of the example let's ignore the fact that calling test like that would cause the function to be called endlessly).

If you did want to refer to your global variable within the function you can always retrieve that by using the 'this' keyword.

Some examples:

```
private var type:int = 4;

private function test(type:int):void{
   trace(type,this.type)
}
trace(type);//outputs: 4
test(3);//outputs: 3, 4
test(type);//outputs: 4, 4
```

Comment: it's not that there's no access to the `type` variable, it's that local scope trumps the class scope. if you name the function parameter something else, you would be able to use `tyoe` without the "this." as it would then resolve to the class scope

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I's becoming clearer to me. Finally I got it!:)

Answer (score 3):

inside your function test, type will be whatever int you pass in. The local scope will override the global scope.

Consider the following code:

```
var type:int = 5
function test(type:int = 6):int{

return type;
}
trace("type is: "+ type); //type is: 5
trace("inside test: " + test()); //inside test: 6
trace("passing 7: " + test(7)); //passing 7: 7
trace("passing type: " + test(type)); //passing type: 5
type = 10
trace("passing type again: " + test(type)); //passing type again: 10
```

As far a passing a var with the same name, no this also will not make a difference.